# JPARepository save() does not update all values to DB. But gives result

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update fields of a MySQL table using JPARepository save(). But save() updates the field which is null but not updating fields which already have some values.

values currently in DB:
place : null
itemcount : 2

New values passes in temp to update
place : Noplace
itemcount : 1

I have tried with 
1. save(),
2. saveAndFlush with @Transaction
3. Fetched entity again before updating it.

```
public Cons updateCons(Cons temp, Cons con) {

Cons tempCons = consRepository.findOneByIdAndConstId(cons.getId(),cons.getConsId());
   // tempCons.setId(cons.getId());

    log.info("before saving cons :{}, count={}",consignment.getConsId(),temp.getItemCount());
    tempCons.setItemCount(temp.getItemCount());
    tempCons.setplaceStatus("Noplace"); // this filed is currently null


    Cons result = consRepository.saveAndFlush(tempCons);
    log.info("after saving cons :{}, count={}",cons.getConsId(),result.getItemCount()); // logs the updated value on itemCount.
```

}

Expected result: itemcount should be updated with new value
place should be updated with hardcoded value "Noplace"

Actual Result: itemcount not updated in db with new value. but place is updated with "Noplace"
 But logs prints new value as count.

Comment: Did you change the status value after your saveAndFlush method?  Also, it is better to post your entire class with info about how to deal with transaction

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you either change the value again (after the logs are printed, in another method), or you run this as part of a transaction which fails somewhere along the way and is therefore not committed.